# Microsoft JWT discovery keys somehow appear and disappear

Tags: jwt

"kid": "l3sQ-50cCH4xBVZLHTGwnSR7680",

discovery url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys

the kid somehow appear & disappear from the keys list. any idea why like that ?
can reproduce the issue in postman.

[image: Postman Request]

Comment: I am facing with this one as well but don't know what is the reason exactly.